# ajax window doesnt work when tag is deeply nested in the DOM

Tags: ajax, jwindow

i am struggeling with a ajax window getting opened in deep nested DOM. I am not that good in jquery so i try to find some help here.
jWindow is supposed to open a new window on click with ajax-content.
For testing i put a Link just under the first DIV. THIS WORKES PERFECT !!!
Then i added some code to generate a TABLE with contains one coloum with a Number which contains the SAME a-tag as the test on top. THIS DOES NOT WORK.

Here is a copy of the DOM(i put horizontal rules around the two a-tags to make it more easy to find them):

```
 <div id="content">
<p>
```

---

```
<a class="get_detail_bill_window" bnr="177" shop="2" href="#">Text Ajax</a>
```

---

```
</p>
<div id="form_selection">
<div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 1em; width: 1200px;">
<div class="t_fixed_header_main_wrapper ui-widget ui-widget-header ui ui-corner-all">
<div class="t_fixed_header_caption ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
<div class="t_fixed_header_main_wrapper_child">
<div class="t_fixed_header ui-state-default ui" style="border: medium none; font-weight: normal;">
<div class="headtable ui-state-default" style="margin-right: 15px;">
<div class="body ui-widget-content" style="height: 340px; overflow-y: scroll;">
<div>
<table id="atcs_sort" style="width: 1182px;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ui-widget-content">2011-10-16</td>
<td class="numeric ui-widget-content">
```

---

```
<a class="get_detail_bill_window" bnr="341" shop="2" href="#">341</a>
```

---

```
</td>
<td class="numeric ui-widget-content">02:25:08</td>
<td class="numeric ui-widget-content">2011-10-16</td>
```

If you have a look at these 2 anchors, they are absolute the same. But the one nested in the DOM does not want to work.

Here is the code of the Document ready:

```
    $(".get_detail_bill_window").on({
click: function() {
    var shop=$(this).attr('shop');
    var bnr=$(this).attr('bnr');
    alert("bin im Click - Shop:  "+shop+" Billnr:  "+bnr);

var a = $.jWindow
({ 
    id: 'detail_bill', 
    title: 'Details of Bill-Nr.: '+bnr, 
    minimiseButton: false, 
    maximiseButton: false, 
    modal: true,
    posx: 450, 
    posy: 50, 
    width: 700, 
    height: 200, 
    type: 'ajax', 
    url: 'sge_detail_bill.php?s='+shop+'&bnr='+bnr
}).show(); 


    a.update();
}
});
```

I tried this to see, if the selector might have a problem:

```
var pars = $(".get_detail_bill_window");
for( i=0; i<pars.length; i++ ){
   alert("Found paragraph: " + pars[i].innerHTML);
}
```

But i found all(the top sample AND the nested ones) of the a-tags with this class.
So, i am totally lost and desperate. No idea why these nested links are not working.

If somebody have a solution, i would be very greatful.

Many Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score -1):

what is your question put short? rephrase plz. but in case i understood correctly, you want to loop throguh all the elements in your DOM
lets say php made it look like 
    <.div id='foo'>
      <.ul>
        <.li><.span id='foo1'><./span><.span id='foo2'><./span><./li>
        <.li><./li>
        <.li><./li>
      <./ul>
    <./div>

and to access each of the inner elements do
    $('#foo foo1').click(function(){// handler in
      $('#foo #foo1').parent().each(function(){// access element, go back to li, loop through all of them
        $('#foo2',this).show();// on click of foo1, foo2 will show (as an example)
      });
    },function(){// handler out
      $('#foo #foo1').parent().each(function(){
        $('#foo2',this).hide();
      });
    });
hope this helps somewhat

Comment: Hello Semur, thanks a lot for your time. But no, i do not want to loop through. The table is already in the DOM with the proper links in each row in the coloumn. I just want, if i click on this ink in a row in this coloumn, to get the window with the ajax-content opened. Like the Link outside this nested structure which works alredy perfect. Please have a look at the 2 a-tags in my description above, They are absolut similar, except that one(which is not working) is deeply nested in the td-tag of the table.